# Css animation change the background color of the button

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a strange problem, I want to add a loader to a button.

To do this, I create a rotation animation for the loading effect. When combining the animation and the disabled state, I have a strange behavior, it looks like there is a double opacity. But it should not be the case. Any idea ?

```
<button disabled="disabled" class="loading">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="text">test</span>
</button>
```

```
@keyframes theAnim {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

button {
  background: rgb(30, 3, 56);
  color: white;

  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &:disabled {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }

  &.loading {
    .icon {
      position: absolute;

      animation: theAnim 2s infinite linear;

      &:before {
        content: "#";
      }
    }

    .text {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/mantalo/pen/RwMWWLE

Comment: What is "double opacity" supposed to mean? Can you describe the difference between the actual and desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Use background opacity

And for you i simplified your animation

```css
@keyframes theAnim {
  100% {
          transform: rotate(1turn);
      }
}

button {
  background: rgb(30, 3, 56);
  color: white;

  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &:disabled {
     background: rgba(30, 3, 56, 0.3);
  }

  &.loading {
    .icon {
      position: absolute;

      animation: theAnim 2s infinite linear;

      &:before {
        content: "#";
      }
    }

    .text {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <button>test</button>

  <button disabled="disabled">test</button>

<button disabled="disabled" class="loading">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="text">test</span>
</button>
```